# Entity Framework Core Self referencing table set null on delete

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a self referenced entity Employee :

```
public class Employee
    {
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Job { get; set; }

    public int? ManagerID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ManagerID")]
    public virtual Employee Manager { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ResponsableID")]
    public virtual List<Employee> IsManagerOf { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EmployeeID")]
    public List<Signature> Signatures { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EmployeeID")]
    public List<Object> Objects { get; set; }

}
```

An employee can have a Manager who is an employee. But if a manager is deleted, I want to set the field `ManagerID` to null.
I've try the fluent API with :

```
builder.Entity<Employee>().HasMany(e => e.IsManagerOf).WithOne(e => e.Manager).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
```

But I got the error :

> FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Employee_Employee_ManagerID' on table
>   'Employee' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

I didn't really understand why it can cause circle, if a manager is deleted only the field managerID of some employees is set to null.

How can I fix this or make a workaround ?

Comment: I don't understand it either (except if it points to itself), but it's coming from SqlServer, so nothing can be done at EF Core side. You have to do it manually before deleting the manager.

Comment: The fluent config you have is fine. However, you've got some really wonky `ForeignKey` attributes that may be causing conflicts. `IsManagerOf` should not have the attribute at all, or if you want to use attribute config, it should be `[InverseProperty("Manager")]` instead. Both `Signatures` and `Objects` likewise should be using `InverseProperty`, but definitely not tied to `EmployeeID`.

Comment: Also not sure what you're doing with a `List<Object>`. `Object` has no properties, so EF is either going to choke, or probably just create an empty table with no purpose. Best to mark that one as `NotMapped`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt `Object` is in fact a custom class totally different from the `object' c# class. I will check for inverseProperty on Signatures and Objects. thanks

Comment: Ugh... you should rename that. `object` is the keyword, but it's backed by `Object`. Naming your custom class the same thing is not only going to lead to confusion for developers, but also likely ambiguity errors, since the `System` namespace is pretty commonly included everywhere.